# Drupal The Settings file is not writable

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Drupal 8, I installed it locally on XAMPP my Mac machine, but in Verify Requirement I got a problem which is

> The Settings file is not writable.
>   The Drupal installer requires write permissions to ./sites/default/settings.php during the installation process. The webhosting issues documentation section offers help on this and other topics.

I tried a lot on Internet but there isn't effective solution, Could anyone has knowledge in this.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, run this command, where `/path/to/drupal/root/` is just that: The path to the folder where you installed Drupal.

```
chmod 644 /path/to/drupal/root/sites/default/settings.php
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and settings.php permissions have set up to 644 already.

Comment: @BogdanChernovol check the permissions on the settings.php parent folder, a.k.a. the `default` folder. Try
`chmod 755 /path/to/drupal/root/sites/default`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

Go to the path - sites/default/ and execute below command.

`chmod -R 777 /files`.

Check this link also https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2018-02-13/solved-the-directory-sitesdefaultfiles-is-not-writable